# PHP API For Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: php, api, outlook

Is there any way to retrieve contact and add edit list of outlook calender? Please advise me.

Comment: How do you see your server side php application accessing an application on a client machine?

Comment: any other way to get list of contacts on webpage?

Comment: Gert your users to export their contacts and then put them on a webpage that way